# Is it possible to show custom dialog just before navigating to other website resulted by address bar change

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to show a dialog when the user navigates to other website changing the url address bar and pressing enter to carry out the navigation?

Comment: impossible to know what really causes the page to navigate away. Plenty of question on this topic in stackoverflow

Comment: It's not possible to detect if the user is browsing away from your website. It is possible to detect if the user is leaving the page with [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), which you could use to ask confirmation. But that's all you can do. You should only do this with a good reason though! Like because there's unsaved data on the page for example.

Comment: Yes, I was playing with popstate event and beforeunload event, but neither works when a user navigate to other website through changing the address bar url. I asked because maybe these early days there is a solution :S

Comment: There's a very good reason why there aren't any better solutions. Back in the old days, this was abused _a lot_ by spammers to prevent users from leaving their websites. Even popping up new browser windows when they closed them. This is known as "browser hijacking". And because of what happened, it's made impossible.